# Problems with setting one onClickListener on many buttons

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have 3 buttons on my Layout. And I've tried to set one click listener on them but my app crashes when it starts.
No warnings in Android Studio.
At first I create new Click listener - buttonsClickListener. Then with switch I separate exe codes for every button. And in `onCreate` method I set listeners to buttons.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
    private TextView mInfoTextView;
    Button buttonSetBackgroundRed =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSetBackgroundRed);
    Button buttonSetBackgroundYellow =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSetBackgroundYellow);
    Button buttonSetBackgroundGreen =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSetBackgroundGreen);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        mInfoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoTextView);

        buttonSetBackgroundRed.setOnClickListener(buttonsClickListener);
        buttonSetBackgroundYellow.setOnClickListener(buttonsClickListener);
        buttonSetBackgroundGreen.setOnClickListener(buttonsClickListener);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    View.OnClickListener buttonsClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.buttonSetBackgroundRed:
                    mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.set_background_red);
                    mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.redColor));
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonSetBackgroundYellow:
                    mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.set_background_yellow);
                    mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellowColor));
                    break;
                case R.id.buttonSetBackgroundGreen:
                    mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.set_background_green);
                    mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.greenColor));
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You can't call `findViewById()` outside of a method. Move those calls into `onCreate()`, after `setContentView()`.

Comment: Oh, thx, not much theoretical knowledge I have). Is it nessesary to set -1 on the question rating?I just want to say that I'm in progress, learning and stuff like that...

Comment: Yes, what mike said is true. You are calling findViewById when the view is not even created so you should be getting NullPointerException whenever you try to set onClickListener to your object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use findViewById() outside of the onCreate() method because the views aren't even created before onCreate() is called. So, there's no view to find. Change your code to the following

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
private TextView mInfoTextView;
Button buttonSetBackgroundRed;
Button buttonSetBackgroundYellow;
Button buttonSetBackgroundGreen;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonSetBackgroundRed =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSetBackgroundRed);
    buttonSetBackgroundYellow =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSetBackgroundYellow);
    buttonSetBackgroundGreen =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSetBackgroundGreen);

    mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    mInfoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoTextView);

    buttonSetBackgroundRed.setOnClickListener(buttonsClickListener);
    buttonSetBackgroundYellow.setOnClickListener(buttonsClickListener);
    buttonSetBackgroundGreen.setOnClickListener(buttonsClickListener);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

View.OnClickListener buttonsClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonSetBackgroundRed:
            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.set_background_red);
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.redColor));
            break;
        case R.id.buttonSetBackgroundYellow:
            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.set_background_yellow);
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellowColor));
            break;
        case R.id.buttonSetBackgroundGreen:
            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.set_background_green);
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.greenColor));
            break;
    }
}
};

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use onClick property of button in xml file and make one call of it in your code like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="btn"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="btn"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="btn"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And in you Activity class make this method,

```
public void btn(View v){
    //Your code on clicked
}
```

by this your code will also reduced.....

Comment: Better to use old one method. Bkz the new one is not working in fragments. But actually It's the answer too

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
private TextView mInfoTextView;
Button buttonSetBackgroundRed =(Button) 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
findViewById(R.id.buttonSetBackgroundRed);
Button buttonSetBackgroundYellow =(Button)     findViewById(R.id.buttonSetBackgroundYellow);
Button buttonSetBackgroundGreen =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSetBackgroundGreen);



mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
mInfoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoTextView);

buttonSetBackgroundRed.setOnClickListener(buttonsClickListener);
buttonSetBackgroundYellow.setOnClickListener(buttonsClickListener);
buttonSetBackgroundGreen.setOnClickListener(buttonsClickListener);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();

//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
}

  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }

View.OnClickListener buttonsClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonSetBackgroundRed:
            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.set_background_red);
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.redColor));
            break;
        case R.id.buttonSetBackgroundYellow:
            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.set_background_yellow);
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellowColor));
            break;
        case R.id.buttonSetBackgroundGreen:
            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.set_background_green);
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.greenColor));
            break;
    }
}
};
 }
```